# Pandas datafram fillna setting value based on datatype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that has data extract from a table. The table can be any given table from the database. The table may have unknown number of columns and datatypes. The database I am using is Redshift.

After get the data in pandas DF, I need to check for nan values in numeric/decimal type of columns
if there are any columns with nan value, I need to change the value to 0

```
col_list_nan = pd.columns[pdf.isna().any()].tolist()

for i in col_list_nan:
  pdf = pdf[i].replace(np.nan, 0)
```

How can I change the column value and return complete dataframe with remaining unchanged columns and with the replaced columns that have 0 instead of nan

Comment: does `df.fillna(0)` work?

Comment: yes, it seems to work, but how do I get the changed pandas dataframe ?

Comment: `df=df.fillna(0)`

Comment: the issue is I need to change value to 0 only for specific columns, I cannot use this syntax..  there can be other column , let's say timestamp.. that creates problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242052/discussion-between-sudhir-jangam-and-enke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you had data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0.5, np.nan, 1], 'b': ['string', 'ok', np.nan]})
```

that looks like:

```
     a       b
0  0.5  string
1  NaN      ok
2  1.0     NaN
```

Then you can select subset of columns using `select_dtypes` and replace NaN values with 0 using `fillna`:

```
s = df.select_dtypes(include=['float'])
df[s.columns] = s.fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
     a       b
0  0.5  string
1  0.0      ok
2  1.0     NaN
```